# How to copy bone transform in edit mode?

Tags: bones, transforms

I have two armatures as below
[image]

How to make the left one into the right one ??

Comment: If I understand well, this will result in two identical armatures? If yes, why don't you simply copy the one on the right? Is it because the one on the left is animated?

Comment: No, because the right one just can't generate rig, I'm using Rigify but somehow it's just throws error, I only move some bones, didn't touch anything else.

Comment: Give a try: copy the left one. place the right one at the same position as the copy. in edit mode delete all bones of this copy. in object mode join the right one to the (now empty) copy.

Comment: Above the bone properties is the data properties tab. Choose it. Right at the top is what armature is assigned to armature object. Set the armature of left to same as armature of right.